# How to use the tap tool with a variable number of glyphs?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to use the tap tool in bokeh to identify not only what element in a glyph was tapped on but also what glyph was tapped. Furthermore the number of glyphs (traces) is unknown before hand.

I tried the code below which plots two glyphs but I have to create two callbacks in order to identify what glyph was tapped on. Is there a way to do this with only one callback. Also what if the number of traces is not known before hand (lets say the next time the code is run there will be 6 traces). How can I then know which trace was tapped?

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import curdoc

#create figure with tap
TOOLS = 'tap'
plot = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600, tools=TOOLS)

# Create Data
trace1_source = ColumnDataSource({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'y':[1, 4, 9, 16]})
trace2_source = ColumnDataSource({'x':[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], 'y':[17, 13, 11]})

# create two traces
trace1 = plot.circle(x='x',y='y', source = trace1_source, size=20, color='red')
trace2 = plot.circle(x='x',y='y', source = trace2_source, size=20, color='blue')

# define behavior
def tap1_callback(attr, old, new):
    print('You selected the first trace')
    print('attr: ',attr)
    print('old:', old)
    print('new:', new)
    return
trace1.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', tap1_callback)

def tap2_callback(attr, old, new):
    print('youselected the second trace')
    print('attr: ',attr)
    print('old:', old)
    print('new:', new)
    return
trace2.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', tap2_callback)

curdoc().add_root(plot)
curdoc()
```

Are there other choices apart from 'indices'for "on_chage'? 
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Does something like this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
import inspect

#create figure with tap
TOOLS = 'tap'
plot = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600, tools=TOOLS)

# Create Data
trace1_source = ColumnDataSource({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'y':[1, 4, 9, 16]})
trace2_source = ColumnDataSource({'x':[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], 'y':[17, 13, 11]})

# create two traces
trace1 = plot.circle(x='x',y='y', source = trace1_source, size=20, color='red')
trace2 = plot.circle(x='x',y='y', source = trace2_source, size=20, color='blue')

class CB:
    def __init__(self, name="SOMETHING"):
        self.name = name

    def callback(self, attr, old, new):
        print()
        print(self.name)
        print('attr: ',attr)
        print('old:', old)
        print('new:', new)
        return


trace1.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', CB("RED").callback)
trace2.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', CB("BLUE").callback)

curdoc().add_root(plot)
curdoc()
```

Comment: Actually this does not quite work. When you run it and click on BLUE it reports correctly but if you then click on RED it reports twice and one is incorrect. The behavior seems to happen when you change colors as you click